# Error While deploying Data Factory ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Have been deploying ADFv2 ARM template to another datafactory within same resource group ,and storage account also in same RG, While i deploy i get error for some linked services.

I have linked service to connect my computer and local db server using Selfhosted-IR ,Both are failing. 
I am passing Override parameters for linked services.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks.

```html
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Failed to encrypt`` sub-resource payload {\r\n  \"Id\": \"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgvs/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/TestADF/linkedservices/ConnOnPremComputer\",\r\n  \"Name\": \"ConnOnPremComputer\",\r\n  \"Properties\": {\r\n    \"annotations\": [],\r\n    \"type\": \"FileServer\",\r\n    \"typeProperties\": {\r\n      \"host\": \"****************\",\r\n      \"userId\": \"************\",\r\n      \"password\": \"*************\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"connectVia\": {\r\n      \"referenceName\": \"OnPremToAzure\",\r\n      \"type\": \"IntegrationRuntimeReference\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n} and error is: Failed to encrypted linked service credentials on self-hosted IR 'OnPremToAzure', reason is: NotFound, error message is: No online instance..",
    "target": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgvs/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/TestADF/linkedservices/ConnOnPremComputer",
    "details": null
  }
} undefined
2019-06-24T13:54:48.9695328Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload {\r\n  \"Id\": \"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgvs/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/balptestadf/linkedservices/ConnLocalHostBackOffice\",\r\n  \"Name\": \"ConnLocalHostBackOffice\",\r\n  \"Properties\": {\r\n    \"parameters\": {\r\n      \"Password\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"String\",\r\n        \"defaultValue\": \"Password@1234\"\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"annotations\": [],\r\n    \"type\": \"SqlServer\",\r\n    \"typeProperties\": {\r\n      \"connectionString\": \"***************\",\r\n      \"userName\": \"***************\",\r\n      \"password\": \"*****************\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"connectVia\": {\r\n      \"referenceName\": \"OnPremToAzure\",\r\n      \"type\": \"IntegrationRuntimeReference\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n} and error is: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0..",
    "target": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgvs/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/testADF/linkedservices/ConnLocalHost",
    "details": null
  }
} undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reason for this error message:

From the error message "**Failed to encrypted linked service credentials** on self-hosted IR 'OnPremToAzure', reason is: NotFound, error message is: **No online instance**"

Make sure self-hosted IR is online, when you are deploying. Otherwise you may get this error message because self-hosted IR will be used to encrypt your payload.

To encrypt the sensitive data from the JSON payload on an on-premises self-hosted integration runtime, run New-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential, and pass on the JSON payload. This cmdlet ensures the credentials are encrypted using DPAPI and stored on the self-hosted integration runtime node locally. The output payload containing the encrypted reference to the credential can be redirected to another JSON file (in this case 'encryptedLinkedService.json').

```
New-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedServiceEncryptedCredential -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name "SqlServerLinkedService" -DefinitionFile ".\SQLServerLinkedService.json" > encryptedSQLServerLinkedService.json
```

For more details, refer "[Encrypt credentials for on-premise data stores in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/encrypt-credentials-self-hosted-integration-runtime)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, I fix this problem by using keyvalut to store credentials and used keyvalut in my pipeline. It did worked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault.